# Sound volume of videos is low after asking for audio device with getUserMedia

Tags: html, ios, video, webkit, getusermedia

We are experiencing what seems to be a very rudimentary issue when playing video in conjunction with accessing users' microphones on iOS.

This is a simplified code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <video controls playsinline id="video_element"
           src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
           onloadedmetadata="{
               navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                   audio: true,
               });
           }">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, we load a video element and ask for the audio device using getUserMedia.
Unfortunately, the audio output of the video is really low (probably the sound is coming out of the headset and not the speaker).

Here is a website running in the wild to experience the issue:
https://low-sound.tiiny.site/

This happens on any iPhone that we tested (iOS 15, 16 models XR, 12, 13) on both Chrome and Safari

We have looked thoroughly into this thread, but it doesn't seem to be our exact issue:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230902#c18

I really hope someone can shed some light on this issue